# change url by htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in htaccess file. I want to redirect by site to another url. example `http://abc.com/index.php` to `http://abc.com/beta/index.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

RewriteRule ^mp/?$ /mp/index.php [L]
```

How can I redirect it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is just one rule like this:

```
RewriteRule (?!^beta(/.*|)$)^.*$ beta%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: It is working dude but I want to display the folder name in the url for eg. http://abc.com/beta

Comment: For that you just need a `R` flag. I have edited my answer accordingly, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following rule to the bottom of the  block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^beta
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/$1 [L]
```